# How to get plain formatted output in csv with shell script for oracle sql query

Tags: oracle, shell, csv, sqlplus

This is my shell script.

```
echo "Start";echo @/opt/apps/Tests/SQLDir/Test1.sql | sqlplus Db1/Db1@//maydomain:port/abc;echo "Finish";
echo "Start";echo @/opt/apps/Tests/SQLDir/Test2.sql | sqlplus Db1/Db1@//maydomain:port/abc;echo "Finish";
```

I have 30 .sql files like this, added in one .sh file which results 30 .csv files

Test1.sql has

```
SPOOL /opt/apps/Tests/OF/output1.csv REPLACE;
select name from username where id = 10 and Sname is not NULL and ROWNUM < = 50000;
```

Test2.sql has

```
SPOOL /opt/apps/Tests/OF/output2.csv REPLACE;
select strname,ctyname from addr where city = 'NYC' and ROWNUM < = 50000;
```

My expected OP in output1.csv is

```
name
Abc
xyz 
pqr
```

My expected OP in output2.csv is

```
strname | ctyname
10-AP    NYC
11-KP    MCH
90-ZP    SDK
```

right now I am getting weird o/p in csv

```
name
-------------------------------
Abc
xyz 
pqr

name
-------------------------------
TYU
KLH

50000 rows selected.
SQL>
```

*So is there any way to remove those additional lines [--------- and 50000 rows selected.] with shell script/sql code?*
*And while executing shell script all sql result rows are getting printed on screen.* how to avoid that?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is your 4 digits Sql*Plus version ?

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/10726850/pifor SQL*Plus: Release 12.2.0.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Following SQL*Plus command should do the job:

```
 set markup csv  on delimiter ' ' quote off
 set feedback off
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/10726850/pifor tried this. But its still giving lines like _name_ and below that ---------------------------- lines in csv multiple times. And at the end of file _14291 rows selected._ and **SQL>** has written again

Comment: You cannot remove columns name displayed as header. But they should not be displayed with `--- ... --- `. I cannot reproduce this. With `set feedback off` SQL*Plus should not display the number of rows.

Comment: @pifor - "You cannot remove columns name displayed as header.".   Sure you can.  just 'set header off'.  And to avoid the page breaks, 'set pagesize 0'.

Comment: @EdStevens: yes. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I must say, your method of passing the name of a script to sqlplus is the strangest I've ever seen.  The usual practice (given your names) would be:

```
 sqlplus Db1/Db1@//maydomain:port/abc  @/opt/apps/Tests/SQLDir/Test1.sql
```

I don't see where your 'echo Start' and 'echo finished' accomplish anything, since there is no clarifying info coming along with it.

It looks to  me like what you want in your scripts would be

```
set echo off trimsp on head off pagesize 0
spool /opt/apps/Tests/OF/output2.csv replace
select strname,ctyname from addr where city = 'NYC' and ROWNUM < = 50000;
spool off
```

BTW, 'spool' is a sqlplus command - a directive to sqlplus itself, not a sql statement.  As such, it does not need a semi-colon at the end.
-- edit
Example of using environment variables on sqlplus command line:

```
username=scott
userpw=tiger
server=myserver
port=1521
dbname=mydb
sqlplus $username/$userpw@//$server:$port/$dbname
```

Though I would question why you need to set them as variables.
And I prefer to use tnsnames rather than ezconnect.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/5732537/edstevens Could you suggest the way to pass variable stored values as db name,pw,port,db name etc to sqlplus. I tried this `DBUN=DB1 DBPW= DB1 Domain=maydomain Port=1521 DBName=abc` and used as  `sqlplus "${DBUN}"/${DBPW}"@//${Domain}":${Port}"/${DBName}"  @/opt/apps/Tests/SQLDir/Test1.sql ` but it's throwing an _ Invalid option errors
_

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the error message in context. I must say you continue to come up with the strangest syntax I've ever seen.  Please see my updated answer for formatted example.